# Install sas7bdat into R version 3.2.0 on Windows 7

Tags: r

I am trying to install sas7bdat from zip file but I'm stuck and not sure what to do next, I should load now the library but have to say that don't know how.
That's what I did so far (besides million other things that didn't work)

```
install.packages("M:/Desktop/sas7bdat-master.zip")
Installing package into ‘\\NFUPCA01/UserData$/UNAGJU/R/win-library/3.2’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
inferring 'repos = NULL' from 'pkgs'
```

Could you please help me?

Answer (score 0):

To load the package you already installed:

> library(sas7bdat)

then you should be able to use the function of the package, that is

> read.sas7bdat(SAS-file)